# How do I get data binding to work both ways, when I'm programmatically changing the user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I have a WPF application, which uses User Settings, and binds it to a `<TextBox>` like this:

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.Folder}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The App.xaml looks like this:

```
<Application x:Class="SampleApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Properties"
             ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <properties:Settings x:Key="Settings"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And here's the App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
    }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        new MainWindow().ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

This works really great one way: My TextBox always displays the content of `MySetting` when the window is shown.

The other way around doesn't quite work as I intend. What *does* work, is when the user manually writes into the TextBox.

What *doesn't* work, is when I programmatically make changes to the TextBox, like this:

```cs
textbox.Text = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
```

In this case, `MySetting` doesn't update until the user types into the TextBox.

My current solution is to do this:

```cs
Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting = textbox.Text;
```

But it defeats the point of having a two-way data binding.

What should I do to have data binding work both ways, even when I'm programmatically changing the user control?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `{StaticResource Settings}`? It would be more typical to use `{x:Static local:Properties.Settings}`. Have you actually posted _real code_ here? I.e. copy/pasted straight from a [mcve]? Would you please make sure you include an _actual_ [mcve]?

Comment: @PeterDuniho. I'm a beginner with WPF. I just followed what was written in the [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patrickdanino/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf/). I didn't know there was another way to achieve this, sorry. In any case, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it defeats the point of having a two-way data binding.

No, not really.

The *point* of two-way binding is so that when the code modifies the source property the UI's target property is updated, and when the user modifies the target property, the source property is updated.

Two-way binding is definitely not there so that you can assign a value programmatically to the target property and have it reflected in a source property that you could have and should been setting instead.

It should be very rare for someone writing WPF code to ever have to name or interact with a UI element defined in XAML. And when that does happen, it should be *only* to implement *user interface* features, such as drag-select, drag & drop, key handling, etc.

Putting it another way: in the MVVM paradigm, the view model data structure is the *only* thing that non-UI code ought to be dealing with. The binding mechanism provides the mediator between the business logic, represented by the view model (and optionally, a model behind that), and the user interface, represented by the XAML.

Indeed, typically if you were to set the target property explicitly, it would discard the binding, causing it to not work at all.

So, the right way to do this is, in the code-behind, to *only* ever interact with the `MySetting` property. If you want to update the value shown to the user, then you need to change the code-behind property that is bound to that value.

Comment: So to summarize: instead of `textbox.Text = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath` do `Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath`, the data binding will update the TextBox accordingly. Got it, thanks.

Comment: Exactly. Sorry I wasn't more explicit above.